One button in foreach loop
I'm working on a project and I'm facing a problem.
I have a loop foreach that displays some elements, i want to have a button so i can update this element, but the button should only be visible when some data is displayed and when the data contains a certain word, and the button should be displayed once, not for every elements.
    <div>
    <span  *ngFor="let item of items; let index = last">
                  {{  item.name }}
                </span>
     <button  *ngIf="item.name.includes('RI')" >
     <div  class="icon-override  size-20 pointer" ></div>
     </button>
     </div>


The button visibility state must be tied to a boolean variable in the controller. You can set the boolean variable using the JS Array#some method.
Try the following
my-comp.component.ts
export class MyComp implements OnInit {
  public isButtonVisible = false;
  public items = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // assign value to `items`

    this.isButtonVisible = this.items.some((item) => item.name.includes('RI'));
  }
}

my-comp.component.html
<div>
  <span  *ngFor="let item of items; let index = last">
    {{  item.name }}
  </span>
  <button  *ngIf="isButtonVisible" >
    <div  class="icon-override  size-20 pointer" ></div>
  </button>
</div>

